# drawRect - image scrolling performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, scroll

My tableview suffers from considerably jarring/unpleasant scrolling as it has lots of images.

During my quest for better scrolling performance, I encountered Loren Brichter's ABTableViewCell https://github.com/enormego/ABTableViewCell

According to the ABTableViewCell paradigm, using `addSubview:` is very expensive, and using `drawRect:` is a much better solution (in terms of performance).

Currently, each of my tableviewcells contains

- a custom UIImageView
- three buttons

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find out how to implement this using `drawRect:` versus `addSubview:` , I only found out how to do this with text (which I don't need in this case).

**So how do I add an image and three buttons using drawRect? And does using drawRect enhance performance (or is this just a text-only thing)?**

Building my first app,

Graham

Comment: I have tried using drawRect for them, but the rectangle is always black, ie, correct frame but no image/content , etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, and I could be wrong, you couldn't add a button in draw rect. Drawrect is more for doing custom ui to a view, not adding components. You could add the image, however, like so.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];

    [img drawInRect:rect];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIView class has drawRect method inbuild. You just need to overwrite that function. In drawRect method you add your imageview.

One more comfortable method is to create a custom tableview cell using interface builder
http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2012/10/uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder.html